# How to distinguish between v2 and v3 of Xeon processors?

Tags: linux, hardware, cpu, x86

I'm trying to determine what processor my server is running.

I tried looking at `/proc/cpuinfo`, using lshw and dmidecode. In all of them I get:

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31220 @ 3.10GHz
```

How do I determine if it is a Xeon E3-1220 v2 or v3?

Answer (score 2):

A v2 would say `E3-1220 v2 @ 3.10GHz`, a v3 would say `E3-1220 v3 @ 3.10GHz`, so it's a v1 (Sandy Bridge). To make sure, you can also check the output of

```
lspci | grep DRAM
```

since each generation has a different DRAM controller.